# Building an anchor menu automatically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some help for doing a menu built automatically with jQuery.

I have the following HTML structure

```
<table width="99%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td height="20"><a href="#descripcion">Descripción</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="20"><a href="#preguntas">Preguntas Frecuentes</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="20"><a href="#incompatibilidades">Incompatibilidades</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

...

```
<a name="descripcion"></a>
<h1>Descripcion</h1>
```

...

```
<a name="preguntas"></a>
<h1>Preguntas</h1>
```

In this case the anchor "incompatibilidades" doesn't exist, so what I need is to create a jQuery script which look for any "a" tag which has its corresponding link.

The result I expect is the following:

```
<table width="99%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td height="20"><a href="#descripcion">Descripción</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="20"><a href="#preguntas">Preguntas Frecuentes</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'll appreciate your help!

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want Javascript to remove the row containing the anchor "incompatibilidades"?

Comment: You want to **add** a corresponding `<a>` + `<h1>`, or you want to **remove** a `<td>` that doesn't have a match?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you could do something like this:

```
    var menu = $("#menu");
    $("a").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var name = $this.attr("name");
        if (typeof(name) !== 'undefined') {
            var links = $("a[href='#"+name+"']");
            var link;
            if (links) {
               link = links.eq(0);
            }
            if (link && typeof(link) !== 'undefined') {
                menu.append("<tr><td><a href='#"+name+"'>"+link.text()+"</a></td></tr>");
            }
        }
    });
```

You have to add "menu" id in a new table to create what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Without testing, and if I get your question correct - you are looking for something like this:

```
$().ready(function() {
    // scan all links in your menu
    $('table').find('a').each(function() {
        // grep href attribute
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        // element does not exist?
        if(! $(target).length) {
            // remove parent row
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

And - as @David Thomas mentioned correctly, you shouldn't be using named anchors, but ids instead - if you do so, you can use the anchor ('#xyz') directly as id selector as I did in the function above.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to **remove** the the table row which contains the mentioned anchor tag which does not exist, you could use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('a[href="#incompatibilidades"]').closest('tr').remove(); // Or detach, possibly
});
```

---

If you would like to **add** in an `h1 + a` and append it to your DOM, you could use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var anchor = $('<a></a>', { 'name' : 'incompatibilidades' });
    var h1 = $('<h1></h1>', { text: 'incompatibilidades' });

    // Append these to the DOM here. 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't be using named anchors, but `id`s instead (the "*`name` attribute on the `a` element is obsolete<sup>1</sup>*"), to give:

```
<h1 id="descripcion">Descripcion</h1>
...
<h1 id="preguntas">Preguntas</h1>
```

Also, using a `<table>` element to present a list is a little non-semantic, since it's non-tabular information; instead use an ordered list, `<ol>`. So, with that in mind, I'd suggest the following jQuery:

```js
$('h1[id]').each(function() {
  var target = this.id;
  $('#toc').append(function() {
    return '<li><a href="#' + target + '">' + target + '</a></li>';
  });
});
```

```css
#toc {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="toc"></ol>

<h1 id="descripcion">Descripcion</h1>
...
<h1 id="preguntas">Preguntas</h1>
```

This approach is based on an assumption that you want to build a table of contents to link to those elements that are on the page.

Notes:

1. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a-constraints.